# Reading numeric data of different types from a file in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have a file, the first few lines of which look like this:

```
1   436.514    0.587    8.318   1  3        8 0.929        7 0.972        2 1.440
2   436.004    0.744    7.020   1  3       10 1.117        9 1.155        1 1.440
3   436.263    0.603    5.029   2  1        9 0.916
4   437.966    0.594    6.086   2  1        9 0.835
5   434.577    1.454    5.820   2  1       10 0.898
6   433.990    1.139    7.596   2  1       10 0.919
7   437.917    0.102    8.485   4  3        1 0.972       11 1.503       12 1.428
8   435.617    0.849    9.510   4  3       13 1.463        1 0.929       14 1.490
9   436.839    0.691    5.880   4  3        4 0.835        3 0.916        2 1.155
10   434.623    1.036    6.798   4  3        6 0.919        5 0.898        2 1.117
11   438.321   39.569    9.683   3  1        7 1.503
12   438.614   39.463    7.420   3  1        7 1.428
13   434.384    1.154    9.304   3  1        8 1.463
```

The problem is I am not able to convert these values which are read as strings in variable called line, and then stored into separate char arrays separated by spaces. But my problem is I am not able to convert these values into appropriate types by using std C++ functions.

I mean that I don't control the values at various places in the file so I cannot provide a predefined function to convert it into that type.

For example:
In the first line, the first value is int followed by 3 floats, then int and so so on. And that too the number of values in every line is not constant. Hence I am not able to convert them into desired type. I have tried `lexical_cast`, which fails to convert the values if they differ from pre defined type.

For example: if I have let's say

```
str = "123";
float num = lexical_cast<float>(str)
```

It gives me an error. The same is true for `stof` or `stod` functions which can convert only a string with that type of value.

This is my code right now:

```
while (i < line.length()){
            if (line[i] != ' '){
                    a[j++] = line[i++];
                    if (i == line.length()){
                            a[j] = '\0';
                    ------->int num = std::stoi(a);
                            std::cout << num << "  ";
                    }
            }
            else{
                    a[j] = '\0'; j = 0;
        ----------->float num = std::stof(a);
                    std::cout << num << "  ";
                    while (line[i] == ' ') i++;
            }
    }
```

The places marked with arrow are the problem areas. Can I by any means just read these values into appropriate variables of proper types easily.

NOTE: I cannot manually insert every variable keeping into consideration its type, because the number of lines is 100000. So that's not possible.

Comment: How do you intend to use (or store) the numbers, after you extract them from the file?

Comment: I want to do further processing on them. Every line corresponds to this: atom number, its x,y,z position followed by its type (which can be 1,2,3,4), followed by its total number of connection. And finally the type of connected atoms and their bond orders. I want every information for further processing.

Comment: You make no statements about the content of the lines except that they may mix floats and ints: is there actually *some* pattern - e.g. it might be int, float, float, float, int, int, int, float, zero or more { int, float }.  If so, you can read the standardised part into named `struct` fields or an `vector` - whichever is more convenient to use, and put the variable-length trailing values into a `vector` of `pair<int, float>` or structs with named fields.  If there's really no pattern, you're basically left with a `vector<vector<boost::variant<int, float>>>`, or store everything in `float`s.

Comment: Yeah there's a pattern: int , float, float, float, int, int, followed by (int,floats) depending upon the last int value

Comment: "*`str = "123"; float num = lexical_cast<float>(str)` It gives me an error.*" It most certainly does not, except maybe for a missing semicolon...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is going to be overkill for you now, I expect.

Still want to show the public in general how elegant code can become if you use a parser generator that knows how to project to you AST data types. Here's a Spirit example that automatically handles all conversions to a `vector<line_rec>` where `line_rec` is:

```
struct line_record {
    int   a;
    float b, c, d;
    int   e;
    // column f is rest.size()
    std::vector<std::pair<int, float> > rest;
};
```

### Code

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c2f3b31c74b244a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

struct line_record {
    int   a;
    float b, c, d;
    int   e;
    // column f is rest.size()
    std::vector<std::pair<int, float> > rest;
};    

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(line_record, a, b, c, d, e/*, f*/, rest)


// define a Spirit Grammar
using Iterator = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;

namespace parser {
    static auto const line = [] {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

        _a_type number_of_pairs;
        rule<Iterator, line_record(), locals<unsigned> > line_parser;

        return line_parser %= skip(blank) [
                    int_ >> float_ >> float_ >> float_ >> 
                    int_ >> omit[ uint_ [ number_of_pairs = _1 ] ] >> 
                    repeat(number_of_pairs) [ int_ >> float_ ] >>
                    (eol|eoi)
                ];
    }();
}

#include <fstream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    ifstream ifs("input.txt");
    Iterator first(ifs >> noskipws), last;

    vector<line_record> all_data;

    if (parse(first, last, *parser::line, all_data))
    {
        cout << "Parsed " << all_data.size() << " lines\n";
        for (auto& rec : all_data) {
            cout << rec.a << "\t"
                 << rec.b << "\t" << rec.c << "\t" << rec.d << "\t"
                 << rec.e << "\t"
                 << rec.rest.size();

            for (auto& trailing : rec.rest)
                cout << "\t(" << trailing.first << ", " << trailing.second << ")";

            cout << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (first != last) {
        cout << "Remaining input: '" << string(first, last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

### Output

Given the input from your question:

```
Parsed 13 lines
1   436.514 0.587   8.318   1   3   (8, 0.929)  (7, 0.972)  (2, 1.44)
2   436.004 0.744   7.02    1   3   (10, 1.117) (9, 1.155)  (1, 1.44)
3   436.263 0.603   5.029   2   1   (9, 0.916)
4   437.966 0.594   6.086   2   1   (9, 0.835)
5   434.577 1.454   5.82    2   1   (10, 0.898)
6   433.99  1.139   7.596   2   1   (10, 0.919)
7   437.917 0.102   8.485   4   3   (1, 0.972)  (11, 1.503) (12, 1.428)
8   435.617 0.849   9.51    4   3   (13, 1.463) (1, 0.929)  (14, 1.49)
9   436.839 0.691   5.88    4   3   (4, 0.835)  (3, 0.916)  (2, 1.155)
10  434.623 1.036   6.798   4   3   (6, 0.919)  (5, 0.898)  (2, 1.117)
11  438.321 39.569  9.683   3   1   (7, 1.503)
12  438.614 39.463  7.42    3   1   (7, 1.428)
13  434.384 1.154   9.304   3   1   (8, 1.463)
```

Answer (score 5):

I've only got a couple minutes, but here's an outline of suitable code, which assumes you want to keep all the data in memory concurrently for some cross-line analysis:

```
struct Data
{
    int a;
    float b, c, d;
    int e, f;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> g;
};


int main()
{
    int line_num = 0;
    std::vector<Data> all_data;
    if (std::ifstream in(filename))
    {
        std::string line;
        while (getline(in, line))
        {
            ++line_num;
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            Data data;
            if (iss >> data.a >> data.b >> data.c >> data.d
                    >> data.e >> data.f)
            {
                int i; float f;
                while (iss >> i >> f)
                    data.g.push_back(std::make_pair(i, f));
                all_data.push_back(data);
            }
            else
                std::cerr << "unable to parse mandatory fields "
                    "from line #" << line_num << " '" << line
                    << "', ignoring and continuing...\n"; 
        }

        ... use all_data for whatever analysis you want...
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "unable to open file\n";
}
```

Notes

- read line by line, then use a `istringstream` to parse out the values
- use an extra loop to read however-many pairs of `int`/`float` values appear at the end of the line

Comment: Wow. We have similar minds. We came up with almost identical datatypes, and even the same name for `all_data` :) The only thing missing is validation of number of trailing pairs.

Comment: @sehe `all_data` - that's funny!  I really did only have a couple minutes to write this answer, and when the OP replied to my query about the line formats saying the number of pairs *"depend[s] upon the last int value"* and I saw that wasn't true, I didn't scan back to notice it actually matched the second last.  Totally agree that checking the line matches the count's better practice.  Good to see spirit used - a terrific library and increasingly useful as the input gets more challenging, so a great skill to share.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to handle the file using a combination of ifstream.getline() and sscanf which tells how many matches it found in a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
    double a, b, c, d, e, f;
    int i, j, k, l, m, n;
    char buffer[160];

    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("data.txt");
    while (!file.eof()) {
        // check if this fails
        file.getline(buffer, 160);

        if (file.eof()) break;

        a = b = c = d = e = f = 0.0;
        i = j = k = l = m = n = 0;

        int res = sscanf(buffer,
                         "%d %lf %lf %lf %d %d %d %lf %d %lf %d %lf",
                         &i, &a, &b, &c, &j, &k, &l, &d, &m, &e, &n, &f);
        std::cout << "Got " << res << " fields" << std::endl;
    }
}`
```